# ¿Como puedo rotar este hexagono, sin rotar la imagen?

Tags: php

Como puedo rotar este hexágono, sin rotar la imagen.
También me gustaría saber cómo cambiar de tamaño la imagen ya genera, osea que el tanto el hexágono como la imagen cambien de tamaño.

Este es el script que utilizo.

```
<?php
// doge.jpg is a squared pic
$raw = imagecreatefromjpeg('img.jpg'); 

/* Simple math here

        A_____F
        /     \
      B/       \E
       \       /
       C\_____/D

*/
$w = imagesx($raw); 
$points = array(
.25 * $w, .067  * $w, // A 
0, .5   * $w, // B
.25 * $w, .933  * $w, // C
.75 * $w, .933  * $w, // D
$w, .5  * $w, // E
.75 * $w, .067  * $w  // F
);

// Create the mask
$mask = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $w);
imagefilledpolygon($mask, $points, 6, imagecolorallocate($mask, 255, 0, 0));

// Create the new image with a transparent bg
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $w);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent);

// Iterate over the mask's pixels, only copy them when its red.
// Note that you could have semi-transparent colors by simply using the mask's 
// red channel as the original color's alpha.
for($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++) {
for ($y=0; $y < $w; $y++) { 
    $m = imagecolorsforindex($mask, imagecolorat($mask, $x, $y));
    if($m['red']) {
        $color = imagecolorsforindex($raw, imagecolorat($raw, $x, $y));
        imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($image,
                          $color['red'], $color['green'], 
                          $color['blue'], $color['alpha']));
    }
}
}

// Display the result
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado de hacer un arrayshift http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-shift.php y el valor quitado lo pones atrás?

Comment: Define "rotar hexágono sin rotar la imagen". ¿Quieres que una de las puntas esté  arriba?

Comment: Como? No comprendo.

Comment: Exacto eso es lo que quiero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta pregunta está dividida en dos partes:

1. Cómo rotar el hexágono
2. Cómo escalar la imagen

La primera es una simple cuestión de matemáticas (como se indica en el mismo código que compartes), la segunda es sólo cuestión de aplicar una función más.

### Cómo rotar el hexágono

Ahora mismo el hexágono se crea porque se copian los píxeles dentro del área especificada en el array `$points`, entonces lo único que tienes que hacer es recalcular los puntos.

Esto es lo que tienes ahora:

```
/* Simple math here

        A_____F
        /     \
      B/       \E
       \       /
       C\_____/D

*/
$w = imagesx($raw); 
$points = array(
.25 * $w, .067  * $w, // A 
0, .5   * $w, // B
.25 * $w, .933  * $w, // C
.75 * $w, .933  * $w, // D
$w, .5  * $w, // E
.75 * $w, .067  * $w  // F
);
```

Para que sea un hexágono con la punta arriba cambie esa parte, por este código:

```
/* Simple math here

           A
          /\    
       B /  \ F
        |    |
       C|    |E
         \  /
          \/
          D
*/
$w = imagesx($raw); 
$points = array(
0.5 * $w, 0, // A
0.1* $w, 0.25 * $w, // B
0.1 * $w, 0.75 * $w, // C
0.5 * $w, $w, // D
0.9 * $w, 0.75 * $w, // E
0.9 * $w, 0.25 * $w // F
);
```

Las coordinadas son un poco a ojo y tendrás que recalcularlas si quieres que sea un hexágono perfecto, pero funcionan (más o menos bien) en mi local:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Cómo escalar la imagen

Para escalar la imagen sólo necesitas la función [imagescale()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagescale.php), que funciona así:

```
imagescale(imagen, nuevo_ancho, nuevo_alto);
```

Así en tu caso podrías hacer algo como esto para redimensionar/escalar  la imagen a 400 x 400:

```
$image = imagescale($image, 400, 400);
```

> Una nota importante: cuando se escala la imagen es importante y no es trivial porque afectará tanto la calidad de la imagen como el rendimiento de tu código:
>
> - Si escalas la imagen una vez que se haya generado el hexágono, tendrás que redefinir la transparencia y además el resultado terminaría pixelado. Pero la imagen se generará rápido.
>
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
> - Si escalas la imagen al principio nada más leerla el resultado será más limpio y se verá mejor, pero tardará más en generar la imagen resultado (porque tendrá que procesar el doble de píxeles)
>
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si ya lo habia intentado hacer asi, pero no sabia como hacerlo y en mis intentos solo logre crean triangulos y rombos xD. Muchas gracias por tu explicacion.

Comment: Un método sencillo es dibujar el hexágono en una cuadrícula y calcular las coordenadas según dónde estén los vértices

Comment: Pero como puedo saber eso, por que de acuerdo al la documentacion de php sobre la funcion polygon, son 6 tipos de cordendas pero solo señala **x**,**y**. Osea cada linea x,y lleba dos pares de coordenadas. La verdad es que me pierdo. XD

Comment: Ya lo decifre yo mismo, gracias una vez mas por tu ayuda.